# Is it okay to update or delete data inside of router.post, instead of .delete/.patch?

Tags: express

I created some example code underneath to show what I mean.
Is it okay to update some data after saving inside of a post route? I often update and save data in a single route, and I never know if it is okay to do this and if there are any consequences of the code that I am unaware of.

```js
router.post('/sync-steam', auth, async(req, res) => {
  const { steamID, steamName } = req.body

  try {
    await req.user.save( steamID )
    await req.user.updateOne( steamName )

    res.send("OK")
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(400).send(err)
  }
  
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is OK to do that. There should not be any issues regarding that as long as your logic that communicates with your database is correct.

However, you should try to follow the convention of REST API, and use the correct method:

- GET for listing/reading content
- POST for creating content
- PUT for replacing content
- PATCH for updating part of the content
- DELETE for deleting content